# jQuery Grid Options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jQuery grid similar to an ASP.NET GridView in the following ways.

- Existing records are read-only, but become editable inline upon clicking edit
- Ability to add a new record in the footer of the grid

Additionally, I would like the ability to be able to re-order items in the grid with drag-and-drop. Which jQuery control(s) would meet all my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid worked very well in a lot of my data grid projects. The development is very active and has a lot of expandable plugins.
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

If what you are really asking is a "Gridview made from JQuery" then the answer is YES. There are several third party tools out there that are made from JQuery with the functionality you need (try googleing).

But, if what you are asking is "GridView that JQuery provides(JQuery Widgets)" the answer is No. They don't provide a widget like that.

Comment: No, the GridView is for example purposes. And, I have tried Googling, but there are a lot of choices out there, none of which I saw that would allow for rows (not columns) to be re-ordered via drag-and-drop as a mechanism for re-ordering the position of data in the grid.

Comment: have you tried extjs? As I am browsing now. I think this will suit your scenario. here is a link [extjs samples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/#sample-2)

Comment: I assure you there are several out there. some are free, some are not. just google more here use this as your starting point [list of gridviews](http://php-team.blogspot.com/2009/05/10-jquery-datagrid-plugins.html)